# AWS CloudFormation Stack update error: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

When creating a stack with CloudFormation, I get this error:

> Stack update error: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]

I can't find a template for adding `CAPABILITIES_IAM` to the CloudFormation configuration.

What are the options for resolving `CAPABILITIES_IAM` errors?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Turns out you need to check a box on the last screen of the stack creation. If you are using the console, just above the 'create stack' button there's a box asking you to acknowledge that you want to allow Cloudformation to modify IAM stuff. You can, of course, create the stack without the acknowledgement, which will cause the stack to fail with the `CAPABILITY_IAM` error (or another error, if a different capability is required).

In CodePipeline CloudFormation you can add it like this to allow execution of the created change_set in the deploy action:

```
Configuration:
        StackName: !Ref GitHubRepository
        ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
        Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
        RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::818272543125:role/events-list-codepiplinerole
        ChangeSetName: !Join ["",[!Ref GitHubRepository, "-changeset"]]
        TemplatePath: MyAppBuild::sam_post.yaml
```

In the aws cli append

```
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

or

```
--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

To your command like this:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name message-store --template-body file://bucket_with_keys.yaml --parameters file://cfg_bucket_with_keys.json --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

This does not apply to cloudformation --validate-template as it is not actually creating the resources.

Comment: for the new AWS CLI version, it should be `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
`

Comment: For more information see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the AWS CLI, you can add an extra parameter to the `aws cloudformation create-stack` command that explicitly states you want these capabilities provided.

(this is the CLI equivalent of ticking the checkbox in the other answer here).

The parameter is `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`, so your command would look like:

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $STACK_NAME --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of the cli param. Added that and full code example above.

Comment: Am I wrong or does not not work with `validate-template`?? My full command: `aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://sqs-template.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

Comment: I came here wondering the same thing. If you see the "error" `"CapabilitiesReason": "The following resource(s) require capabilities: [AWS::IAM::Role]"` then that just means your template is valid and you'll have to specify the return capability when creating the stack. [Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html)

Comment: Template will validate without the command - it is only needed when creating the stack

Comment: There's a github issue talking about this as well: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/51

Answer (score 9):

Just above the create stack button, turn on acknowledge in the console.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case someone comes here from Google (like I did) and is using Terraform, make sure you add a capabilities argument:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "cloudformation_stack" {
  # ...
  capabilities = [ "CAPABILITY_IAM" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If "`CAPABILITY_IAM`" is not supported, you can try "`CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If anybody face the same problem trying to deploy using SAM, you just need to add the --capabilities flag:

```
sam deploy --guided --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

[using-iam-capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#using-iam-capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

In the case you are using SAM,

- Possibility 1: use `sam deploy --guided` and at the prompt:

"SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation"

answer yes.
However it will not work if you need the `CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`.

- Possibility 2: pass it as argument in the cli

```
sam deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

or

```
sam deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

or both:

```
sam deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

- Possibility 3: edit the `samconfig.toml` file (or however you named the config file) in this way:

```
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
```

which enables you to simply use `sam deploy` every time without arguments