# InsufficientCapabilitiesException [CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM] when creating a stack with IAM policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I get this error when I run create-stack for a cloudformation template that contains IAM policies.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name iam-stack --template-body file://./iam.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --profile dev
```

An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Stack update error: Requires capabilities : \[CAPABILITY\_IAM\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246108/aws-stack-update-error-requires-capabilities-capability-iam)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Change `--capabilities` to  `CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`

> If you have IAM resources with custom names, you must specify
>   CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM. If you don't specify this parameter, this action
>   returns an InsufficientCapabilities error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html

Answer (score 17):

As per AWS docs,
**If you specify a Role name in cloud formation, you must specify the CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM value to acknowledge your template's capabilities** [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename)

So your command should be

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name iam-stack --template-body file://./iam.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --profile dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed both `CAPABILITY_IAM` and `CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` capabilities for a resource of type "AWS::IAM::Role".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#createStack-property

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS CodePipeline to deploy an EC2 using a CloudFormation stack, there is an option called "Capabilities" from which you can select CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass capability as below if you're not letting CloudFormation name your IAM resources.
Change from `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` to `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`.