# Terraform - Receiving Error with CloudFormation Capabilities

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform so I am sure that I am just missing something simple, but when attempting to deploy a CloudFormation stack, I am encountering an error when applying capabilities.

Here is my stack resource:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "member_remediation" {
  name         = "smx-sharr-member-remediation"
  capabilities = [CAPABILITY_IAM, CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]

  parameters = {
    SecHubAdminAccount                    = var.parameter_SecHubAdmin
    CreateS3BucketForRedshiftAuditLogging = var.parameter_CreateS3
    LogGroupName                          = var.parameter_LogGroupName
    LoadAFSBPMemberStack                  = var.parameter_LoadAFSBPStack
    LoadCIS120MemberStack                 = var.parameter_LoadCISStack
    LoadPCI321MemberStack                 = var.parameter_LoadPCIStack
  }

  template_body = file("${path.module}/cf-templates/aws-sharr-member.yml")
}
```

This is what the stack provides when trying to deploy in the console:

[image: Stack Capabilities]

And here is the error Terraform is providing to me when performing a plan:

```
Exception Error in plan -
Error: Invalid reference

on .terraform/modules/aws-securityhub-master/module/main.tf line 1120, in resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "member_remediation":
1120: capabilities = [CAPABILITY_IAM, CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.

Error: Invalid reference

on .terraform/modules/aws-securityhub-master/module/main.tf line 1120, in resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "member_remediation":
1120: capabilities = [CAPABILITY_IAM, CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

I'm not sure what attribute or resource reference the capability is requiring OR how to write it up in the resource layout. I am not finding many examples of CF stacks being deployed leveraging the capabilities option.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**NOTE:  I have looked over the following question on Stack Overflow already - it didn't help me in this case:**

[AWS CloudFormation Stack update error: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246108/aws-cloudformation-stack-update-error-requires-capabilities-capability-iam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument type for `capabilities` is `set(string)`. It appears you are attempting to resolve undefined first class expressions. You probably meant to cast the elements as literal strings, which we can do with the normal syntax:

```
capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
```

Comment: Ah, something so simple, that was my mistake. Thank you so much!